# Hide ^^^^-notation from pdftex

Tags: pdftex, tex-core

The following example gives when compiled with pdflatex the error

`! Text line contains an invalid character.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\fi
\begin{document}
abc
\ifluatex ^^^^20ac\fi
\end{document}
```

It is possible to get around the problem by using another char and changing its catcode e.g. inside the `ifluatex`:

```
\ifluatex{\catcode`\!=7 !!!!20ac}\fi
```

But I'm wondering: Is there a way to hide such invalid characters from `^^^^`-notation in some way globally in pdflatex?

Comment: `\ifluatex\input{20ac.unicode}\fi` and have a file for each unicode character. But that doesn't sound like a good solution, does it? :-/

Comment: @tohecz: sound like cheating ;-). Also one would probably get problems in some places (additional spaces, \input not allowed).

Comment: I think the easiest thing is to not use `^^^^^` but instead just use the character directly in utf-8  €  then you can load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` for pdftex

Comment: couldn't you use `\char"20AC` instead of `^^^^20ac`?

Comment: @Herbert: In some places certainly but you couldn't e.g. change the catcode of ^^^^20ac.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I was trying to write a "pure ascii"-class which can be used with pdflatex and lualatex/xelatex. It is nowadays probably not really a problem is a class is encoding dependant but I was interested if it is possible to avoid it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see you've accepted that other bloke's answer already but I'll note that you could use  €  in the class without introducing any encoding requirement on the users document eg `{\inputencoding{utf8}€}` would only mean that those two bytes were in utf-8.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The question is if I can always been sure that a class/style-file is read as utf8. As an example: if you write this in a utf8-file `\XeTeXinputencoding "cp1252" ^^^^20ac €` then the `^^^^20ac` will still come out "right" despite the fact that it had been read with the wrong encoding but the € will be wrong. The second problem is with the readability of the source: The € is not so problematic, but when you have chars like zero width joiner or chinese etc then ^^^^-notation is much less error prone and the editor doesn't have to be able to show all sort of exotic chars.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm English with a UK keyboard you don't need to persuade me that ascii is easier to type than all these weird symbols:-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The invalid character is `^^^`, that is, `0x1E`; LaTeX, by default, makes all characters from `0x01` to `0x1F` invalid, with the exception of

```
0x09 0x0C 0x0D
```

that is, tab, line feed and carriage return (category codes 10, 13 and 5).

A workaround could be making this character ignored:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \catcode`\^^^=9
\fi
\begin{document}
abc
\ifluatex ^^^^20ac\fi
\end{document}
```

Assuming you don't need `^^^` anywhere in `pdflatex` code, this should keep TeX happy.

Comment: Imho this is perfect. I can't imagine what harm it should do as `^^^` would give an error anyway.

Comment: This is so genuine!